# Альтернативы использования JDBC CachedRowSet

Tags: java, jdbc

Приветствую!

Можно ли использовать `CachedRowSe` без подключения к базе данных, полностью самому формируя эту структуру?

Если нельзя, подскажите пожалуйста реализацию `RowSet`, в которой это возможно.

**Цель**: передачи структур данных(с возможностью самостоятельной генерации данных без БД) в систему, работающую на RS.